# How do I share java AsyncContext between servlets?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, asynchronous

I am currently learning website programming, java servlets with javascript to be precise, and I just learned how to use an AsyncContext in a single servlet. I was wondering if it would be possible for AsyncContexts to be shared between servlets, so that one user could send another user (viewing a different webpage) a message, for example. Or is it impossible and I just do not understand the concept?

Comment: what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share async requests between users. The async context retains a reference to the request and response objects (which are effectively a reference to the underlying network connection to client) and therefore cannot be shared between users.